# 2sxc App import fails (404)

Tags: import, 2sxc

Trying to import any app into 2sxc, but keep getting message "Had an error talking to the server (404)".  The url it is trying to hit is http://www.dnndev.me/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/app-sys/ImportExport/ImportContent.

Repro steps:

1. Download this package http://autoinstall.2sexycontent.org/Packages/2SexyContent-GettingStarted-01.00.06.zip (because autoconfigure, per this tutorial https://2sxc.org/en/install-basic-content-types-and-templates, 500's, but appears to be trying to find this package)
2. Add a Content module to my page
3. Click Pencil->Admin on the new module
4. Click App
5. Click Import Parts
6. Select the package, hit import
7. Error message appears

Note: this also fails when using a package exported from a functioning DNN install with the same DNN and 2sxc versions.

Info: 
DNN 9.0.2.00 (366)
2sxc App and Content 9.14.0
.NET 4.6
Windows Server 2012, SQLExpress 2012, IIS 7.5

Thanks a ton for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in 2sxc 9.x - it's resolved in newer versions. I recommend 9.32.1 LTS - see https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/releases